# Deleted answers are listed in the order they were posted - can this be changed?

Tags: feature-request, answers, deleted-answers

Oftentimes I notice that the count of answers that I've written *reduces* (even though I did not explicitly delete any of my answers).

Certainly, this happens when a question is deleted, but if the question is one that I have invested a lot of time into answering, I would like to revisit the deleted question and either

- save a link for my reference, or
- petition un-deletion by casting a vote to undelete
- flagging a moderator. It sometimes happens that an OP, on getting their answer, would prefer to delete the question because of "sensitive material", or for whatever other reason.

For these reasons, it would be desirable to see what answers of mine were most recently deleted. However, if I go to the Deleted Answers tab, answers are listed in order of *when they were posted*, not *when they were deleted*.

To understand why this is a problem, here's an example. Say, if I answered a question on the 20th of July, and the OP deleted it today (19th september), the deleted answer would now be listed much further down the list, and not at the top. And since I don't know which answer was deleted, I wouldn't know to scroll down to the 20th July answers and look there. You should understand I have *hundreds* of deleted answers, so sequential searches are not an option.

I've tried looking on the data explorer for useful queries, [and there were one or two](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148959/find-deleted-answers-by-user), but they did not work.

I'm not aware of a feature that lets you see deleted answers by order of deleted date. If there isn't, I think there should be.

---

***Edit***; Searching for:

```
user:me is:a deleted:1
```

Will display all deleted answers and is a working solution for anyone over 10k ([Thanks, Jon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356736/deleted-answers-are-listed-in-the-order-they-were-posted-can-this-be-changed?noredirect=1#comment515498_356736)). However, this is worth considering as a feature for < 10k users.

Comment: Um... does doing a search for `user:me is:a deleted:1` then ordering by "active" give the results you're after?

Comment: @JonClements Hmm, I didn't know you could do that? But I tried it and it just shows me all my answers. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Did you try the version that didn't have the `deleted:1` spelt out properly? It'll show all of your deleted answers - but won't distinguish between the reason they were deleted (ie - not those specifically deleted because the question was)

Comment: @JonClements Yes, the `:1` works! I didn't know you could do that, so if you could post it as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: It's an answer that'll work for you - I'm not sure if there's another convenient way to do so if you happened to be less than 10k rep though... so it's not quite an answer :p

Comment: @JonClements there is no solution for <10K users.  They can't search deleted content at all

Comment: @psubsee2003 surely you should be allowed to see the content you own?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no, `deleted:1` works only for 10k users amd mods. IIRC the feature for 10k users was only added within the last couple of years as well